# State in Reactjs holding the previous state value, how to update the state with new edited form value

Tags: reactjs

OnSubmit function using ref took all the form data and added to the state value in react(still in the same page) now the user change one input field in the form and submit is it the changed value is collected and updated to the state but the state values show's both previous form value and new edited form values. I want only new form values in the state. kindly help

I tried to clear the state value by making it undefined, null on every submit function

```
constructor (props) {
...
this.state = {
  data :[]
}


render {
...
...
<table>
<select ref={country0} name=country0>
 <option value="china">china</option>
  ....

<select ref={country1} name=country1>
 <option value="London">London</option>
  .....

 onSubmit = event => {
  ....
 let country = [];

 //for loop (looping table row's for iteration)
   temp = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['country' +i]);
        country[i] = temp.value; //adding value to the array

 const info = {country : country};//country array
 const data = this.state.data;

 data.push(info);

 this.setState({
   data:data
  });

//also tired 
const data = [...this.state.data, info]

this.setState({
  data:data
});

displaying state value 
 Actual :

china
London

on edit (user changes China to Japan and London to China) 
I got

  china  ---- previous value
  London ----- previous value
  Japan
  china

Expected :

Japan
china
```

Comment: It's a bad question with bad writing and bad code example.
please edit your question and use clean code to explain your question.

Comment: Hi novonimo , I just followed the instructions and posted the question and to make it simple I explained my scenario in simple words. And I don't understand what bad you find in the code I just given the state , render and on submit event and actual & expected result

Comment: Any way I fixed my issue my changing the state variable from [] to {}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are appending data to your array instead of replacing it with new values. You should initialize a new array if you don't want to retain previous results.

```js
const info = {country : country};//country array
 const data = [];

 data.push(info);

 this.setState({
   data:data
  });
```

Comment: I was simply copying his code and applying a simple change. No need to be rude.

Comment: Thank u for the response. As said, now {this.state.data} will holding some data correct ? now again i want to update the new value to the state then we will get previous State with current form data. That's the problem. Did you understand what i mean??